# What do these sounds mean when it is raining?

Tags: stardew-valley

Sometimes when its raining in the game, I hear these low tone sounds (watch your ears - the rain is a little loud):

- [Sound 1](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByNi02RoHJUITG1jU3RpTEp5Vkk)
- [Sound 2](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByNi02RoHJUIWU1yLXRENS1yNVE)

Do these sounds signify something or are they just background noise?  I don't think I hear them every time it is raining which makes me wonder if they are some sort of significance.  I also think the same sounds sometimes play when you go to bed for the night.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These sounds are simply frogs croaking. You can sometimes see frogs fleeing when you cut down weeds and grass, or while it rains.

[image: A frog near the mountain lake during the rain]

Comment: Yeah as far as I know they're just for atmosphere.

Comment: I saw the frogs and I did think that the noise was from them, but I wanted to be sure.

Comment: Well, the noise isn't actually generating from them or anything. It's just ambient noise in that regard, but it's meant to be frogs.